# Ruby regex doesn't recognize beginning of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace the "text" contains http link with the actual HTML markup for this link.

Here is my Ruby code

```
url_check = Regexp.new( '(\A|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\r\n\t<]*)', Regexp::MULTILINE |    Regexp::IGNORECASE )
self.gsub!(url_check, '\1<a href="http://\2">\2</a>')
to_s
```

Here is a test case:

```
This is entrance page for the service (using HTML):

http://foobar.org/resources?format=html

Let us pick the "contributions" namespace: http://foobar.org/
```

The link is created only for the second case, but not for the first (which has several line breaks before)

Comment: Could you add the expected output? I must be missing something here..

Comment: It is working for me. http://pastebin.com/UY2udJ1a creates both links. You could generalize the character class in the first group to `(\A|[\s])` to catch any whitespace rather than just newline and space.

Comment: Hi Andrey, maybe it is not multiline but dotall.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using \b (word boundary) instead of new-line/start-of-the-line detection:

```
.gsub!(/\b([\w]+?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \"\r\n\t<]*)/i, '<a href="\1">\1</a>')
```

you don't need "http:" in replacement as you already match for protocol.